# How do viruses/bacteria survive in extremely cold conditions?

Tags: bacteriology, virology

So, recently, i watched a video, it was about a anthrax outbreak in Siberia.

The cause, supposedly were reindeer carcasses, infected by anthrax. Due to the thawing ice they resurfaced, and that lead to a outbreak.

So, i was wondering, how do viruses/bacteria manage to survive in extremely cold weather conditions?

I already did check Google and Youtube (in multiple languages), had a look into the book "Purves Biology" for answers, yet i did not find something specific enough to answer my question.

Comment: Anthrax is caused by the bacterium *Bacillus anthracis*, which is a spore-former. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endospore

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Does not answer the question properly. I was wondering how bacteria or viruses generally manage to survive in such cold conditions. You only told me about how Bacillus anthracis survives in the cold. But what about other bacteria, do they survive differently than this virus? Or are "endospores" the general approach to survive these conditions? And what about viruses, do they do the same?

Comment: Thank you for adding more detail — however, unless you confine you question to anthrax your question is too broad. Bacteria  have been evolving for billions of years and there can be no universal answer that covers all of them — for example many of them won't survive freezing. Likewise viruses have probably been around for just as long (or possibly even longer) and whether they should be thought of as "alive" is debatable.